# How can remove backslash in value by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-events

**if** $(this).val() have backslash remove backslash in it by jQuery. How is it?
`1111\/11\/11` -> `1111/11/11`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
$(this).val().replace(/\\/g, '');
```

You have to use two backslashes to get the \ character. A single backslash is used for control characters such as \r \n etc. Using the double backslash escapes this and gives you what you want.

Answer (score 4):

```
var str = $(this).val().replace('/','');
```

Comment: it will replace first occurance only not all the occurance will be replace

Comment: @kleinohad: also there is some change in the question now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\\/gi, ""));
```