# removing backslash in a string with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, json, string, twitter, replace

When I query twitter feeds, the returned profile url contains backslashs
and looks like:

```
"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/2419298032\/image_normal.jpg"
```

how to remove the backslashes to make it look like:

```
"http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/2419298032/image_normal.jpg"
```

Thanks a lot!

P.S.  seems

```
x=x.replace(/\/gi, "");
```

doesn't work...

Answer (score 11):

`x = x.replace(/\\/g, '');`

You have to use two backslashes to get the \ character. A single backslash is used for control characters such as \r \n etc. Using the double backslash escapes this and gives you what you want.

See also: [how can remove backslash in value by jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758734/how-can-remove-backslash-in-value-by-jquery)